# como recuperar dados json php com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

como posso fazer para recuperar os dados vindos de uma pagina em `php` com o `ajax`. pois estou conseguindo o resultado mas não esta vindo para o `jquery` ele não me traz os valores

codigo da consulta

```
if(isset($_POST['cep'])){
    $cep = $_POST['cep'];
    $newCep = str_replace("-", "", $cep);

    require_once "../Model/Correios.class.php";

    $p = new Correios("15991182","{$newCep}","0.300","5","11","11","0","04510");
    $s = new Correios("15991182","{$newCep}","0.300","5","11","11","0","04014");

    $pac = $p->getValor();
    $prazoPac = $p->getPrazoEntrega();

    $sedex = $s->getValor();
    $prazoSedex = $s->getPrazoEntrega();

    $retorno = array("pac"=>$pac, "prazoP"=>$prazoPac, "sedex"=>$sedex, "prazoS"=>$prazoSedex);

    echo json_encode($retorno);
  }else{
    header("location:../");
  }
```

codigo do ajax

```
$.ajax({
                  url: 'Controller/consultaCep.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: dado,

                  success: function(r){
                    valorP = r.pac;
                    valorS = r.sedex;
                    prazoP = r.prazoP;
                    prazoS = r.prazoS;

                    alert(valorP);

                  $("#pacCorreio").val(valorP);
                  $("#pacCorreio").html("PAC - "+prazoP+" dias após postagem R$ "+valorP);
                  $("#sedexCorreio").val(valorS);
                  $("#sedexCorreio").html("Sedex - "+prazoS+" dias após postagem R$ "+valorS);
                  $("#todo").show();
                  }
                })

              });
```

Comment: A *callback* `success` está sendo executada, ao menos? Não ficou claro o problema.

Comment: sim esta executando tudo so que nao esta chegando os valores do php no `alert(valorP)` ta me retornando `undefined`

Comment: eu executei o `console.log` e ele me mostra os valores do  `echo json_encode($retorno);`

Comment: No `$.ajax`, coloque `dataType: 'json'` para informar ao jQuery que o retorno será JSON. Veja se muda algo.

Comment: consegui resolver. tem que converter novamente esse `json` do `php` para `js` com o `JSON.parse` converti e funciono ele me trouxe os resultado